# Can we have a template not on type but on operation

Tags: c++, templates, comparison

I'm new to C++.
I currently have 2 classes with the EXACT same code except at some point one class uses the '<' operator and the others uses '>'.

Is there any way to merged those classes and declare a template on '' operator?

Comment: You can merge the two classes and have a strategy that is supplied to the class (see strategy pattern) which encapsulates this difference. The client of the class will somehow supply the correct strategy to use.

Comment: That would be a solution but not really appropriate according to the rest of my design ;)
thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, if your problem is really limited to `<` and `>`, then you can make a base class taking a boolean stating whether to use one or the other.

```
class base
{
protected:
    base(bool use_less) : m_use_less{less}

    some_return_type my_fn(some_args args)
    {
         ...
         const bool cmp = m_use_less? a < b: a > b;
         ...
    }

private:
    const bool m_use_less;
}
```

If lines such like

```
const bool cmp = m_use_less? a < b: a > b;
```

repeat too many times in your code, you can consider making an inline method that does this.

---

If you want, though, you can generalize the comparison much further, as many standard library algorithms (for example, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)), which does exactly this.

Typically, standard-library algorithms solve it as follows (the following assumes you're operating on integers):

```
#include <functional>

// Pass the comparison as a template argument
template<class Compare=std::less<int>>
class my_class
{
 private:
    // A comparison object
    Compare m_cmp;

 public:
    some_return_type my_fn(some_args args)
    {
        ...
        const bool is_less = m_cmp(lhs, rhs);    
        ...
    }

};
```

By default, this class uses `<` (via `std::less`). If you want to use `>`, simply instantiate with [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is exactly what I was looking for.
I thought of using a boolean as in your first solution but was looking for something more 'pro'

Comment: @LeLaboureur Indeed, IMHO, the second is more "standard library like". Good luck.

Comment: Your comparison object is required to be default-constructible and stateless?

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, but am unsure if you're asking the OP or me.

Comment: @AmiTavory: You. It's your answer :-) If I meant someone else I would have used the "at" syntax.

Comment: @KerrekSB Due to your comment, looked again at my answer, and modified it (thanks!). Indeed, your point about the unnecessary restrictions I inadvertently imposed on the functor are correct (in my meagre defense, I first thought the question was about a function, only later realized it's about a class - that made a mess of the code a bit). Thanks again (but please do comment if there's anything further).

Comment: For the OP that's fine.  For general use, it won't work with a simple function with signature `bool (Predicate)(T lhs, T rhs)` - which seems a bit sad. `std::sort` solves this by having two overrides: One for `std::less`, and one having an explicit comparison functor argument.